# How to implement twice nat with iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I want to do twice nat.

Design is:

```
LAN - A 192.168.1.10/24 OpenSwan VPN Public IP 5.5.5.5  <------VPN-----> Public IP 6.6.6.6 Open Swan --- > LAN B 192.168.1.20/24
```

When i ping from source `192.168.1.10` I want to change source to `1.1.1.x/24` and destination to `2.2.2.10/24`

So machine in LAN A `192.168.1.10` will ping destination `2.2.2.10` with source nat IP `1.1.1.10` and packet will hit `192.168.1.20`

Due to overlapping subnet I cannot put route of  `192.168.1.20` in LAN routing table as it conflicts, so i want to ping a dummy IP `2.2.2.10` and when packet reach Openswan VPN box it make destination translation to `192.168.1.20`

So what would be NAT statement on Site A OpenSwan?

( Note i dont have access to site B openswan , so all changes required on Site A openswan )

Answer (score 2):

Is there a requirement for LAN A and LAN B to use the same subnet, or could that be changed?

I also sincerely hope the 1.1.xx and 2.2.xx IPs you give are purely illustrative - in the real world, you would want to use RFC1918 addresses.

On a basic level, what you describe is applying both Source and Destination NAT, i.e. SNAT and DNAT.

So in theory, the below should work:

```
-t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2.2.2.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.20
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.10 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.10
```

Unfortunately, if you do not have access to site B's VPN server, then this will not work.

And the reason it will not work is that while the machine on LAN A is trying to reach 1.1.1.10, your LAN A VPN server needs to translate that back to 192.168.1.20.
There is also the issue of what LAN B's VPN server should do with the 1.1.1.10 source IP - you would need routing in place for the packet to be sent back to its originator, and it seems (to me) a whole lot simpler to just have LAN A use 10.1.1.1/24

And as you have mentioned, you can't make your LAN A VPN server route correctly to 192.168.1.20, because your LAN A VPN server believes that subnet to be local to it.

Adding a specific route *might* help (e.g. ip r add 192.168.1.20/32 via IP), but this all sounds a little brittle - I would have thought a much more workable solution would be to split your /24, and assign a /25 on either side of your VPN (if you *must* maintain the same LAN IPs on both ends).

So I would tend to think your best bet is trying to change LAN A.

A different /24 from B's would work, and it would also work to have a /25 on either side of the tunnel.